# udev rule at boot time

Tags: boot, usb, udev

I have a udev rule to execute a simple command when a USB device is plugged (any device).

The rule is:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'xhost +local:pi; sudo -u pi xscreensaver-command -lock'"
```

This works quite well and the screen is blocked when I plug something into any of the USB ports.

But this isn't working when I already boot with the device plugged in. I expected to boot with the screen already locked.

What can I do to execute this rule at boot time? Is it possible?

Comment: Try `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger` and if that works incorporate it into boot after appropriate sleep of 10 seconds or so.

Comment: `udevadm monitor` shows that this will fire off a change action, but the action needed is an "add".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X server starts late, so your script run in vain before it's up. It could be worthy to create a python script as daemon which watch for devices using `pyudev`.

Comment: Thanks @user.dz, that was the answer. I used a Python script to do the task and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an python script I use for my Sharkforce mouse... it should be easy to adopt it for your scenario...
For more infos see: https://pyudev.readthedocs.io/en/v0.13/api/index.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pyudev import Context
import os
context = Context()
for device in context.list_devices(subsystem='input', ID_INPUT_MOUSE=True):
    if device.sys_name.startswith('event'):
        name = device.parent['NAME']
        #print(name)
        test = name.find('SHARKFORCE')
        if test != -1:
            os.system('synclient TouchpadOff=1')
```