# udev rule launches bash script at hotplug but not at coldplug/reboot

Tags: bash, scripts, python, systemd, udev

basically this [udev rule at boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015207/udev-rule-at-boot-time) , but I read somewhere that it was the systemd daemon that handles all the coldplug while udevd handles only the hotplugs.

How to do it with the linux systemd way instead of a python listener please?

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?